# Where is this "Rockery" treasure located?

Tags: genshin-impact

There's a model of a rock formation at the top of Wangshu Inn.  The flavor text seems to indicate there is some sort of treasure associated with it? That said I've not seen any mountains that look like the model here.

[image]

Is there any treasure associated with this? And where can I find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The users on the [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Genshin_Impact/comments/j79s0o/rockery_basin_in_wangshu_inn/) community have found where this rock formation is located. According to screenshot provided by the users, it is on the road north of Liyue Harbor.

The treasure that is located there is a precious chest.

> [image: Map to rock formation]